# Is it irrational to sanitize random character strings for curse words?

Tags: random, filtering, filter

If you exposing randomly generated strings or strings with data encoded in them (Product keys).  Is it irrational to sanitize them for curse words to avoid the client possibly getting offended in the rare case an offensive word is generated.

Anybody ever have a customer get offended by a randomly generated curse word?
Anybody out there ever code logic to filter them out?

Thanks

**Edit**

One time after developing a product key generation system which had customer data encoded into it.  As a joke we wrote a program to see what customer input would generate funny words.

Comment: At first blush, this sure sounds silly.  What about a customer offended by the name of a country?  Some folks don't think Israel should exist, and go through great pains to say "The Zionist Entity" and things like that.  How far down this road should you go?  Do you have any additional information on where or how the line gets drawn?  Is this the seven words you can't say on television list?

Comment: I'd be curious if there is a consistent procedure for checking for "obscene" letter combinations on license plates. It seems like you could use a similar algorithm.

Comment: THe odds of randomly generating any particular 4 letter word are like 1 in half a million.

Comment: "Anybody ever have a customer get offended by a randomly generated curse word?" Yes: http://www.clickondetroit.com/news/4050844/detail.html

Comment: School, user would have had to *type* C*NT: http://www.papercut.com/blog/chris/2008/05/12/if-an-infinite-number-of-monkeys%E2%80%A6/

Comment: I can't find it now, but I remember a question from a programmer who had generated sample or test data for an application using Markov chains to create realistic but fake personal names and other information. The customer was indeed offended by the occurrence of profanity and the poster was looking for filtering methods.

Comment: Above link broken. See https://web.archive.org/web/20090116040027/https://www.clickondetroit.com/news/4050844/detail.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Don't generate random strings with vowels and then you don't have to worry about curse words.

Comment: Great idea. Should work in most languages as well.

Comment: While I generally agree, you might still end up with strings like "fck" or "fvck".  This probably still falls under "don't optimize for the insane."

Comment: @luke: Yeah, I think that this method will get rid of the "real" curse words. Imagined or "kinda looks like a curse word if you squint really hard" words are still the user's problem :)

Comment: Using guids likely will prevent any of these issues.

Comment: @luke Good point, but people who want to see things to be offended by will see something no matter what you do.

Comment: Should Y be considered a vowel?

Comment: Oh and for the love of Mike, please don't put in characters that render similarly (ie, O and 0, I and 1, p and q, d and b, l and 1, l and I).  Use only 1 from each pair.

Comment: @plinth Actually create an array of acceptable characters and exclude vowels and characters that can be misinterpreted, then randomly pick from that array.

Comment: @plinth Also a lot depends on the font you print or display these codes in. Using a computer type font will clearly indicate the character usually.

Comment: Yeah, fonts meant to use in consoles typically are very carefully designed so that '1', 'I', 'l', and '|' are easily recognizable; these are the same fonts that put a slash through the '0'.

Comment: This is much better than having ONLY vowels, because you get so many Hawaiian curse words with all vowels.

Comment: Regarding what luke said, you may want to eliminate not only vowels, but other letters or numbers that look like vowels, and you may also want to have a short list of offensive words with their vowels removed which you scan for and remove as well.

Comment: It's perfectly ok to generate random strings.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, on the grounds that anyone who would be offended by something they saw in a randomly generated string can think of more things they find offensive than you can sanitize.

Don't optimize for the insane.

Answer (score 19):

Microsoft omits the following from their product keys:

`0 1 2 5   A E I O U   L N S Z`

I omit those from [0-9A-Z], and once the key is generated, I match against [a list I found](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~leon/mcs425-s08/handouts/char_freq2.pdf) of two-letter combinations most common in English, and regenerate the key if there is a match. For speed, I edit the list of letter pairs by first culling from that list the pairs that are already prevented due to their inclusion of a character in the stripped list ('HE' can't exist if the key is generated from a character set that does not include 'E'), then convert some from 'E' to '3', as in 'H3' instead of 'HE', etc. I have also added a few of my own, like 'KK' and 'CK' for edge cases. One could also omit '3' for speed as necessary, although the more characters you omit the fewer unique keys can be generated.

Probably not a perfect solution, but it's fast enough for my needs and prevents almost all English words from being generated, offensive or not.

Comment: Hi... just wondering if there is any reference to this omission of characters in a public document that Microsoft might have published? Would be handy to validate my use of this list.

Comment: For copy-pasting reference: `bcdfghjkmpqrtvwxyBCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY346789`

Comment: I don't think that some of these characters are omitted because of profanities.
Lowercase L looks like uppercase i, zero looks like O, Z like 2, S like 5. These are just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest solution is to generate from a 'sanitized' alphabet; use a set of characters that cannot possibly form words. One suggestion in one of the answers is hexadecimal which is an excellent choice, or otherwise drop some critical letters from the alphabet.

Note that just dropping vowels is not going to do the job... it is all too easy to infer them from the remaining consonants.

Answer (score 5):

That makes sense to me. I mean, it would be a pretty bad PR disaster if someone posts a picture of your product, with this stamped on the back of the CD case:

12345-67890-F**KU-ABCDE-FGHIJ

It sounds funny but you never know what kind of sense of humor the person will have who happens to pick up that package.

Comment: This isn't just a hypothetical, either.  It really happened, with a cabbage patch doll: http://www.clickondetroit.com/news/4050844/detail.html

Comment: Above link broken. See https://web.archive.org/web/20090116040027/https://www.clickondetroit.com/news/4050844/detail.html

Answer (score 2):

See those items tagged with [clbuttic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clbuttic)

Comment: Damn, someone killed those tags, try a search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clbuttic

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to plainly avoid vowels. A product key like JKL-YOUAREMYFRIEND-0001-KK may not be offensive but it doesn't sound like serious business either.

Answer (score 1):

Limit your randomly generated "words" to hex characters and I don't believe you'll have any English-language curses. This also pushes you down a path of not spending too much time on your random word generator.

Of course, there may be some language where you can curse with hex digits, but then you're not likely to know/filter those curses anyway.

Comment: 0xdeadbeef, 0xaffe (german for "monkey").

Comment: dead beef?!?! As a vegetarian I'm HIGHLY offended.

Comment: A bad dad bedded a dead babe.

Comment: @wilberforce - I like it, but I don't think any of those would be considered "curse" words :-)

Comment: Some people find necrophilia offensive! Prudes. (:

Answer (score 1):

If you are just worried about product keys, I would stick to hexadecimal digits, maybe even a guid would work for you. Probably no chance of a "naughty" word being generated with these constraints. You could also just stick to numbers as well. If you must have random strings with all letters of the alphabet, it is probably better safe than sorry so I would do the filtering.

Comment: Oh hell, the 4s don't render like it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

We are using a random string generator for a security key that will be sent to customers, and did *not* omit vowels from the allowable characters, etc. No word of a lie, one of the strings it generated was "7D9WAF*CKS" ...! Luckily, this was discovered during development, and we are now going to restrict the allowable characters. Whew!! That was a close one - happy to have found this posting !

Answer (score 1):

A very fun [tale of woe](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator.aspx) to read with a similar situation to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's certain conceivable, but I wouldn't devote much time to it, especially if you've got letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using randomly generated, phonetic-sounding passwords for one webapp I wrote. I did end up hard-coding a list of "dirty" words that aren't acceptable, but the list that matched my pattern ended up being pretty short.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have no chance to collect all curse words in all world languages. Those words usually don't appear in dictionaries.

Comment: A GOOD dictionary will include colloquialisms and slang.  The OED certainly includes swears in it, and all other sorts of filth my ancestors would be ashamed to admit they did on a weekly basis.